# Functional equation $f(f(k+1)+3)=k$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functionas $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $$f(f(k+1)+3)=k$$.
Obvious solution is $f(k)=k-2$. I have found following:
$k+3=f(f(k+1)+3)+3\implies f(k+3)=f(f(f(k+1)+3)+3)=f(k+1)+2\implies f(k)=\begin{cases} k+a,\quad 2\nmid k \\ k+b,\quad 2\mid k\end{cases}$ for some $a, b\in\mathbb{Z}$. And I can't continue after this. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: See also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h350187p3259731

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done is good. We can continue to search for constraints on $a$ and $b$.

First, $a$ must be even: Because, if $a$ was odd, then setting $k=0$ gives
$$0=f(f(\underbrace{1}_\text{odd})+3) = f(1+a+3) = f(\underbrace{4+a}_\text{odd}) = 4+2a \implies a=-2,$$
contradiction.

Now that we know that $a$ is even,
$$0=f(f(\underbrace{1}_\text{odd})+3) = f(1+a+3) = f(\underbrace{4+a}_\text{even}) = 4+a+b \implies b=-a-4.$$

In summary, $a$ is even and
$$
f(k)=\begin{cases} k+a,  & k \text{ odd} \\ k-a-4, & k \text{ even}\end{cases}
$$

(and $a=-2$ gives the "obvious" solution $f(k)=k-2$).